# How do I perform assignments in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So while creating test cases for tress in Python 3.6, I was wondering if there is a good way to perform actions such as assignment in the list comprehension. Should I use lambda?

I want to insert

```py
Prev_Node.next = Node(i)
Prev_Node = Node(i)
```

into

```py
iList = [1,2,3,4,10]
Prev_Node = Node(iList[0])
l1 = [Node(i) <Any assignment action?> for i in iList[1:])]
```

Thank you for your time in advance,

Comment: Comprehensions should not be used for mutable operations.

Comment: You can only do this in Python 3.8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Selcuk I see assignment expression; it's like lambda. Thank you

Comment: @Jens So I am trying to construct a Linked List via list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Use iterators to traverse your list, don’t fiddle around with `.Next` etc to build your own.

If you’re looking for list head and tail, then you could do something like:

```
int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
node_list = [Node(i) for i in int_list]
head = node_list[0]  # Get the head Node and leave it in the list.
head, *tail = node_list  # Get the head Node and remove it from the list.
```

and iterate like

```
for node in node_list:
    print(node)
```

Take a look at the various [list function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) on how to further manipulate an existing list.

Comment: Would unpacking list into a single head and a tail connect them give the objects themselves? Thank you !

Comment: No, you will get the head, and the tail list. If you want to construct a list from the head and tail, you could `[head,] + tail`. Python (and other dynamic languages) will hide implementation details like `next` from you, and you won’t need that anyway. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. I guess python list is a more direct implementation of Linked List...  May I ask what you mean by [head,] + tail? do you mean recursively recollect them?

Comment: Yes, Python internally implements a list of linked elements but you don’t need to know these details here. The `[head] + tail` prepends a single `head` element to the beginning of the list: `[head]` is a list and `+` concatenates the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do assignments within a list comprehension. Trying to do so raises a `SyntaxError, e.g.:

```py
[x = 0 for _ in range(1)]
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suppose an awful hack to try to achieve this could be to define a function which you call in the list comprehension which does the assignment (using global variables). But this would be much worse than just using a normal for loop instead of a list comprehension. Basically, any time that using a list comprehension doesn't work right away, you're probably better off with a for loop. It'll be easier for you to program and for others to understand.

```py
# hacky; don't do this
def set_x(val):
    global x
    x = val

[set_x(i) for i in range(3)]
x # 2
```

Comment: As you said, that is a really bad idea. Because you are forcing python to create a list of `n` empty values. What happen if you want to do an operation 1000000000000 times? you will create a list of that size fill with `None`. I'm just writting this as a note. The explanation was good tough. So remember guys: **Do not use comprehensions for mutable operations**

Comment: Correct for Python 3.6 which the OP asks about. Assignments are possible in comprehensions starting with Python 3.8.

Comment: I've got a few things to (re)learn once 3.8 is out! And I'm sure a new wave of SO questions about that feature

Comment: @Selcuk, If you reed the PEP you will see that they are possible but at the end you are returning something and keeping those values. The use case is different than to **just** make the assignment inside the comprehension

Comment: Thank you @Nathan for the response. Would your last suggestion still be hacky if it wasn't using global, and is actually updating a private variable?

Comment: If you do an assignment within a function and the variable isn't global, that won't affect a variable of the same name in the global scope, so it wouldn't change anything outside of the function. Or do you mean changing an attribute on a class? That would be slightly less bad I suppose, but it's still a bad practice, as @Netwave notes, to use a list comprehension as a one-line for loop if you're not interested in the list being built up. I don't think I'm quite understanding your goal, though. What should the list `l1` contain at the end?

Comment: I think this abuses a comprehension. If you want to do something while iterating over a list, use a `for` loop. `x` in the above example will always be the last element of the list, so you might as well use `x = [-1]`

Comment: @Selcuk, yeah, just wanted to make a not on why it should not be used here. I wasn't pointing that you were wrong or anything my friend :)

Comment: @Netwave No offense taken. Just wanted to confirm you :)